# I am trying to save attendance in my Django attendance app but keep getting TypeError, expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to create attendance for `my student_attendance` model but keep getting the TypeError. I have tried everything, checked several solutions on this platform, none have worked.

The error looks like this:

```html
TypeError at /attendance/student/
expected string or bytes-like object
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/attendance/student/?reg_class=1
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected string or bytes-like object
Exception Location: line 75, in parse_date
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Mrs Onajide\Desktop\school_management_system\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
```

My View

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .forms import SearchEnrolledStudentForm, AttendanceForm, DateForm
from student.models import EnrolledStudent
from academic.models import ClassRegistration
from .models import StudentAttendance
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

def student_attendance(request):
    forms = SearchEnrolledStudentForm()
    class_name = request.GET.get('reg_class', None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        class_info = ClassRegistration.objects.get(id=class_name)
        student = EnrolledStudent.objects.filter(class_name=class_name)
        count = student.count()
        attendance_formset = formset_factory(AttendanceForm, extra=count)
        formset = attendance_formset(request.POST)
        date = DateForm(request.POST)
        list = zip(student,formset)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form, student in zip(formset,student):
                mark = form.cleaned_data['mark_attendance']
                StudentAttendance.objects.create_attendance(class_info.name, student.roll, mark, date)
                return redirect('home')
```

My Model

```
from django.db import models
from academic.models import ClassRegistration
from student.models import EnrolledStudent
from django.utils import timezone

class AttendanceManager(models.Manager):
    def create_attendance(self, std_class, std_roll, std_id, datel):
        std_cls = ClassRegistration.objects.get(name=std_class)
        std = EnrolledStudent.objects.get(roll=std_roll, class_name=std_cls)
        std_att = StudentAttendance.objects.create(
            class_name=std_cls,
            student = std,
            status = std_id,
            date = datel
        )
        return 
    def class_attendance(self, std_class, date):
        ctd = ClassRegistration.objects.get(name=std_class)
        std_att = StudentAttendance.objects.filter(class_name= ctd, date=date)   
        return std_att 

class_attendance = (
    ('Present','Present'),
    ('Absent','Absent'),
)

class StudentAttendance(models.Model):
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(ClassRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(EnrolledStudent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(choices=class_attendance, max_length=9)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = AttendanceManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['student', 'date']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student.student.personal_info.name)
```

My Form

```
from django import forms
from academic.models import ClassRegistration

class SearchEnrolledStudentForm(forms.Form):
    reg_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ClassRegistration.objects.all())

class_attendance = (
    ('Present','Present'),
    ('Absent','Absent'),
)

class AttendanceForm(forms.Form):
    mark_attendance = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=class_attendance)

class DateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a form instance instead of a date to `create_attendance`.

See this line in your code:

```
date = DateForm(request.POST)
```

Your `date` variable contains a form with data bound from the POST. You need to do the same thing you're doing with the formset you create with `AttendanceForm` and check if the form is valid, then pull the value of `date` out of `cleaned_data`:

```py
dateform = DateForm(request.POST)
if dateform.is_valid():
    date = dateform.cleaned_data['date']
```

This will give you the correct value to then submit to your call to `create_attendance`:

```
StudentAttendance.objects.create_attendance(class_info.name, student.roll, mark, date)
```